# Capture video without sound in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps, video-capture, capability

I want to write a Windows Store App that can capture video (without any sound) and take pictures. Imagine a digital camera: you can preview the picture on the screen of your device before pushing the button which takes the pic.

The problem I'm facing now is the fact that the `Windows.Media.Capture` namespace has only classes for objects that capture video with sound (`CameraCaptureUI`, `MediaCapture`). I'm not troubled by the objects' capabilities, but by the fact that I will have to include in the manifest of the app the Microphone capability and it does not make sense for the app to use it. I need a class that uses only the Webcam capability.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer and I thought I should share it. I'm sorry for answering my own question, but here goes:

One can specify in the settings of the MediaCapture object, when initializing it, that it will use only the Video part:

```
var mediaCaptureMgr = new MediaCapture();
var captureSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
captureSettings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
await mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync(captureSettings);
```

RTFM!